# WiFi fails on HP Envy x360 m6

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

Booted Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from USB, and WiFi cannot be started. The kernel log shows:

```
pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e0
pcieport 0000:00:0c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer,  id=00e0(Receive ID)

Device [8086:9d13] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[ 0] Receiver Error

IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
```

Above in the logs I saw this:

```
Ill wifi 0000:01:00.0 Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
```

Same error with 7265D-18 and 7265D-17

I did not perform the install, but am simply running the RAM version. By chance would a newer version of the driver be available after installing?

Thanks for any pointers,
Tony

Comment: Forgot - model is m6-aq005dx

Comment: Do the install, update the system. This adapter is supported. If it does not work, you may need to install firmware. Most likely it will be installed with updates.

Comment: Still fails:iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[repeats for 18 & 17]
iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Unsupported splx structure 
iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm 
iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready

Comment: Still fails after Ubuntu install. Same errors about loading iwlwifi-7265D-1x.ucode. See error about "Unsupported splx structure". Same error "link is not ready" when IPv6 tries to "NETDEV_UP".

Comment: Please post output of `dmesg | grep iwl` TO YOUR QUESTION, NOT TO COMMENTS.

Comment: It is OK that it fails to load 19,18,17 and loads 16.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post output of `rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Solved! Turns out it system seems to find and use only the first WiFi module, and it was trying to use some asus one that showed up before the one for the Intel chipset. I added it to the blacklist of modprobe, and things started working. Not very impressive that the user can't see which module/interface the system is trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

See comment above. Problem was caused by a conflict of available WiFi modules. For some reason the kernel was finding an "asus" WiFi module in addition (and prior to) the correct Intel module. The system doesn't do a very good job of handling multiple found interface, and an even worse job of telling the user about it. Adding it to the blacklist of modules solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install rfkill

```
$sudo apt-get install rfkill
```

then run this command

```
$rfkill unblock all
```

check if the wifi is working. If not do this

```
$sudo nano /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

then you will see some settings. Turn everything to "true"

reboot your system

give this command in terminal

```
$rfkill list
```

you'll see that there is softblocked and hardblocked. All of them should be 
"no".

If it's not "no" then you need to somehow turn them to "no". I did this and 
worked for me

```
$sudo modprobe -r acer-wmi

$cd /etc/modprobe.d

$sudo nano blacklist.conf
```

Then add blacklist acer-wmi as a new line at the end of the file.

then save the file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> ,close it and reboot the system. It should work